# Get a color 'Grouping'?

Tags: .net, colors

I have a .NET program that has color settings that can be any RGB value (no alpha). I am looking to be able to group objects not just by their color but by their color 'grouping' (just my made up name, don't know if there is a better name). I would like to be able to place colors into things like 'reds', 'blues', 'greens', etc., and deal with them that way.

I was thinking of making some type of class that I can set predefined colors and get a 'deviation' from these standards and group them with the closest one or something like that, but I'm wondering if there is a better way out there before I go down that road.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this easily? Or some library out there that can do this?

Comment: The term is "hue", Color.GetHue() returns a number you can group by.

Comment: Thanks.  I looked at that but it doesn't do a great job of pulling out what I needed.  I have fiddled with it and using a mix of hue, lightness, and RGB color numbers and it seems to be working reasonably well.  Thanks for the tip...